# How to display heart symbols unicode to webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode-string

I have at table in which there is list of symbols with their details and on click of `Get Code` button i am passing values to modal to show hear symbol details to modal.

Here is my table one example list code :

```
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 30px;">❤</td>
    <td>Classic Heart Emoji</td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" class="code-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
    onClick="sendvalue('Classic Heart Emoji','#x2764','#10084','U+2764','Heavy black Heart','Dingbats','&#x2764');">Get
            Code</button></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my bootstrap modal code :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Symbol Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                        <div class="modal-emoji" id="mysymbol" style="font-size:75px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
                        <h3 class="site-text grey" id="title">
                            <br>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="custom-text" id="symbol">
                        </div>
                        <p class="site-text grey" id="code">
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <p class="site-text grey" id="unicode">
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <p class="site-text grey" id="unicodename">
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <p class="site-text grey" id="unicodeblock">
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="code-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js function :

```
function sendvalue(title, html1, html2, unicode, unicodename, unicodeblock, symbol) {
        console.log(html1, html2,unicode)
        document.getElementById("mysymbol").innerHTML = symbol;
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = "Symbol / Emoji: " + symbol;
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = '&'+html1+"; OR "+'&'+html2+";";
        document.getElementById("unicode").innerHTML = "<b>Unicode   :   <b>" + unicode;
        document.getElementById("unicodename").innerHTML = "<b>Unicode Name  : </b> " + unicodename;
        document.getElementById("unicodeblock").innerHTML = "<b>Unicode Block  : </b> " + unicodeblock;
    }
```

The problem is when in modal unicode is converting into symbol but i want to show that symbol html quivalent code exactly as i am passing this code `#10084` as string in function and then in function appending `&` with it inside function to show on screen like `&#10084`. But it is converting this code to symbol. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `innerHTML`, use `innerText` or `textContent`.

Simply put, using `innerHTML` tells the browser to render *what* the entities describe, while `innerText` will parse the text it self.

Using the other options, you can of course not use the `<b></b>` tags, since this will also be rendered as the text values. You can however switch between inputing strings with both `innerHTML` and `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer  should be at the following url: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm

It appears you have to use the code &#9829.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I want to display this code  `&#9829` as exactly in my bootstrap modal but when i am passing it into my javascript on click function like this
onClick="sendvalue(''&#9829')" so on modal it is converting this code into symbol. But i want to show this code exactly as modal.